# How to run pydantic.mypy with mypy

Tags: python, mypy, pydantic

i have mypy.ini config file:

```
[mypy]
python_version = 3.10
plugins = pydantic.mypy

[pydantic-mypy]
init_forbid_extra = True
init_typed = True
warn_required_dynamic_aliases = True
```

and libs into requirements.txt:

```
pydantic==1.10.5
mypy==1.7.1
```

When i try run mypy --show-traceback, i recieve this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mypy/semanal.py", line 6525, in accept
  File "mypy/nodes.py", line 1140, in accept
  File "mypy/semanal.py", line 1608, in visit_class_def
  File "mypy/semanal.py", line 1693, in analyze_class
  File "mypy/semanal.py", line 1727, in analyze_class_body_common
  File "mypy/semanal.py", line 1814, in apply_class_plugin_hooks
  File "pydantic/mypy.py", line 140, in pydantic.mypy.PydanticPlugin._pydantic_model_class_maker_callback
  File "pydantic/mypy.py", line 284, in pydantic.mypy.PydanticModelTransformer.transform
  File "pydantic/mypy.py", line 463, in pydantic.mypy.PydanticModelTransformer.add_construct_method
TypeError: __init__() missing required argument 'default' (pos 6)
```

whats wrong???